# Why `double i = 3.3, j = 1.1; int k = i/j; printf("%d\n", k);` gets 2?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, double

I found the result of double/double is not correct:

```
double i = 3.3, j = 1.1;
int k = i/j;
printf("%d\n", k);
```

the result is 2, why??
**Debugging:**

[image]

But:

```
float i = 3.3, j = 1.1;
int k = (int)(i/j);
printf("%d\n", k);
```

**Debugging:**

[image]

Comment: Of course the result is 2.  The real questions here are why you think it would be anything else, and specifically what do you think the result should be ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think you are able to answer these real questions yourself :).

Comment: I think it should be 3 not 2.

Comment: Why do you think it should be `3` ? What do you think the value of `i/j` would be if it were a `double` ?

Comment: 3.0, but I now know that the binary format can't represent 3.3 correctly:)

Comment: What on earth does that debugging window show?

Comment: @Rubby; If you know that then why you asked this question? Is this a test for us?

Comment: @haccks Sorry, should I delete it???

Comment: just curious where did you get the debugging screen from :P

Answer (score 2):

3.2999 / 1.10 gives 2.99 and something which on converting to integer yields the output 2

Answer (score 2):

A double cannot represent 3.3, even if you write 3.3 in your code the double will store it as 3.2999999999999998. (It cannot store 1.1 exact either, it will be 1.1000000000000001)

So `i/j` is performing 3.2999999999999998/1.1000000000000001 whose result will be stored as 2.9999999999999996

converting a double to an int truncates the value, it does not round it to the nearest integer, so 2.9999999999999996 will be converted to 2

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken?lq=1) applies just as well to C with IEEE 754 floating points, and have many further resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
double i = 3.3, j = 1.1;
int k = i/j;
```

because of the way decimal numbers are represented in memory, the result of i/j is actually 2.999999...the compiler will convert the resutl `i/j` from double to int because k is a int. And that's how you end up with a result of 2

Comment: I think he knows the compiler will convert it to `int`. The question is why the resulting integer is 2 and not 3, because 3.3/1.1 = 3.

Answer (score 0):

As you know that `3.3` can't be represented in binary format correctly and same for `1.1`, evaluating `k = i/j` results in

```
3.2999999999999998 / 1.1000000000000001  < 3
```

Assigning this  to `int` type `k` truncate it to `2`.